# Using firestore SDK on cloud function getting error: Cannot encode type

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a function that will add data to firestore on authentication trigger.

```nodejs
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.addUserData = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data;
    const userUid = user.uid;
    return db.collection('peoples').doc(userUid).set({
        name:user.displayName,
        uid:user.uid
    });
});
```

But it gives the error

> Error: Cannot encode type ([object Undefined]) to a Firestore Value
>       at Function.encodeValue (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:775:11)
>       at Function.encodeFields (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:646:36)
>       at Function.fromObject (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:202:55)
>       at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:272:39)
>       at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:425:8)
>       at exports.addUserData.functions.auth.user.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:9:46)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)

## askfirebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that one of the values you're passing in is `undefined`. Given you code, the `uid` is unlikely to ever be `undefined` so that leaves the display name as the likely cause.

A user profile is not required to have a display name, so you code should handle the case where it doesn't.

```
const user = event.data;
const userUid = user.uid;
const userName = user.displayName ? '';
return db.collection('peoples').doc(userUid).set({
    name: userName,
    uid: userUid
});
```